# need some help sending query in python

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to send delete query but its not working. this is view.py part:

```
def remove_sveti(request):
    if not request.is_ajax():
        raise Http404
    sveti = Sveti.objects.all()
    if sveti.pk == request.GET['pk']:
        sveti.remove()
        return HttpResponse('{"success":true}')
```

and this is my models.py:

```
class Sveti(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = 'sveti')
    position = models.IntegerField()
```

in browser console is 500 error, and in editor console it writes this:

```
File "D:\workspace\trello_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 132, in get_response
    raise ValueError("The view %s.%s didn't return an HttpResponse object." % (callback.__module__, view_name))
ValueError: The view trello.views.remove_sveti didn't return an HttpResponse object.
[05/Mar/2014 16:15:17] "GET /index/remove_sveti?pk=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 9676
```

I am using sqlite as database.

Comment: i am using Django framework, and Sveti() is just the name of table

Comment: I think I saw one thing it should be sveti = Sveti.objects.all(), right? instead of sveti = Sveti()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `if sveti.pk == request.GET['pk']:` is False, you don't explicitly return anything and the view returns `None` instead.

To delete a record, you'd need to use [`Model.delete()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete)

```
if sveti.pk == request.GET['pk']:
    sveti.delete()
    return HttpResponse('{"success":true}')
return HttpResponse('{"success":false}')
```

would remedy both errors, or by returning a 404 response (not found).

However, I don't see you actually querying for the right `Sveti` object in your view, perhaps you meant to use the [`get_object_or_404()` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) here:

```
def remove_sveti(request):
    if not request.is_ajax():
        raise Http404
    sveti = get_object_or_404(Sveti, pk=request.GET['pk'])
    sveti.delete()
    return HttpResponse('{"success":true}')
```

The `get_object_or_404()` function will raise a `Http404` response if the object by that primary key doesn't exist.

Comment: Object {success: false} is what was returned

Comment: @Nikgaru: And what do your server logs show when the 500 is returned? Perhaps you can switch on DEBUG mode to see the error in the browser too.

Comment: it says that: AttributeError: 'Sveti' object has no attribute 'remove'

Comment: @Nikgaru: Corrected; it's `.delete()`, not `.remove()`.

Comment: well it was my error, i should have written sveti.delete(), not sveti.remove().